# when exactly is the setter for <f:metadata><f:viewParam> invoked

Tags: java, jsf, lifecycle, viewparams

I have defined an **f:metadata** section on my xhtml page as shown below with a **f:viewParam** as shown in the below excrept:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" (...)>

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="cust-id" value="#{CustomerCEVController.customer}" 
        converter="#{customerConverter}" converterMessage="blah blah."
        required="false"
    />
</f:metadata>


    <ui:composition template="/templates/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
        (...)
        <ui:define name="body">
        (...)
```

.. and have declared a CustomerConverter class for the *cust-id* parameter. The converter class **getAsObject** method for the property *cust-id* and the getter method for the backing bean *customer* field are all called in the **PROCESS VALIDATIONS** JSF lifecycle phase called **BEFORE** the setter method for the *customer* field which is called in the **UPDATE MODEL VALUES** life-cycle phase. As a result, at the time where the getter is called, the field is not properly initialized by the converter. So the sequence is like this (where CustomerCEVController is the backing bean class):

[ **PROCESS VALIDATIONS phase START**       ]
[  CustomerConverter#getAsObject called     ]
[  CustomerCEVController#getCustomer called ]
[ **PROCESS VALIDATIONS phase END**         ]
[ **UPDATE MODEL VALUES START**             ]
[  CustomerCEVController#setCustomer called ]

I am reporting the sequence based on the interspersion of logging output and a lifecycle listener I've registered.
Am I missing something and if not, how can I ensure that the customer field is properly set by the converter before it is ever accessed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence is absolutely fine. I don't understand why exactly this forms a problem for you. Perhaps you're doing some business job in the getter or setter while it doesn't belong in those methods at all? You'd need a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` instead to perform that business job.

The getter is been called during the end of validations phase because at that moment the decision will be made whether to publish a [`ValueChangeEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent.html) or not. For that the initial ("old") value is needed which will then be compared to the submitted/converted/validated ("new") value. When those values are inequal, then both will be passed as "old" and "new" value of the published `ValueChangeEvent`.